# Is it possible to have multiple context roots in Maven generated application.xml?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee

Maven is able to generate the `application.xml` file for an EAR and puts the context root in it that has been defined in the EAR's `pom.xml`. 
Is it possible to have an `application.xml`generated that has multiple context roots?

Or is the only possible way to achieve this to write the `application.xml` myself and use this rather than the generated one?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use [applicationXml](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html#applicationXml) option in goal ear of Maven ear plugin. For more information on how to use it take a look at its [usage page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/usage.html).
Regards.

Comment: This is the solution of writing the `application.xml` by hand. Though it is really not a big issue I wonder if it could be generated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean different context roots for different WARs inside your ear (since each web module can have exactly one context-root). In that case, you can explicilty configure your war modules inside the ear's pom:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
           <modules>
             <webModule>
               <groupId>artifactGroupId</groupId>
               <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
               <contextRoot>/context-root-module1</contextRoot>
             </webModule>
             <webModule>
               <groupId>artifactGroupId</groupId>
               <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
               <contextRoot>/context-root-module2</contextRoot>
             </webModule>
          </modules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: In fact I meant two have two context roots for the same web module.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this would violate the javaee spec / application.xsd, which allows only one context-root per web module.